# php show the array into rows

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Assamese
    [1] => Javanese
    [2] => English
    [3] => German
)
Array
(
    [0] => Amharic
    [1] => Oromo
)
```

I wanted to fetch the data so I used foreach loop like this

```
foreach($values as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

It is showing result like this

```
AssameseJavaneseEnglishGermanAmharicOromo
```

But I want the data in 2 rows beacuse  as I have two array and the data should separated  with the comma. So the data should be show like thuis

```
Assamese,Javanese,English,German in 1st row
 Amharic,Oromo in 2nd row
```

**Remember** I need the data in two rows so that I can save data of 1st row into a row of database and another row to save into 2nd row of database

Comment: is that multi-dimensional array or two separate arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I'm putting the two arrays together so you can separate them by index in the $mix array, then imploding each array into a string and separating by comma:

```
$arr1 = array("Assamese", "Javanese", "English", "German");
$arr2 = array("Ahmaric", "Oromo");

$mix = array($arr1, $arr2); //Or use loop to add multiple arrays

$i = 0;
foreach ($mix as $arr) {
    $r = implode(", ", $arr);
    echo $i .": ".$r . "<br />";
    $i++;
}
```

Returns:

> 0: Assamese, Javanese, English, German
>
> 1: Ahmaric, Oromo

Comment: thanks for the answer but its not multidimensional array

Comment: @NewUser so is one array, or two arrays separately?